# ggplot2: grouping a barplot by several instead of a single categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(mean_swd = c(4.0000, 5.3333, 6.3333, 5.6666, 3.6666),
             afd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             union_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             spd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             fdp_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
             green_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
             linke_pot = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))

> df
  mean_swd afd_pot union_pot spd_pot fdp_pot green_pot linke_pot
1   4.0000       0         0       0       0         0         1
2   5.3333       1         1       1       1         1         0
3   6.3333       0         1       0       1         0         1
4   5.6666       0         1       0       0         1         1
5   3.6666       1         1       1       0         1         1
```

The `pot` variables represent a potential (1) or no potential (0) to vote for a party, `mean_swd` stands for a mean score on an attitude scale (from 1-7), the rows represent individuals.

I want produce a grouped `barplot` using `ggplot2` that actually puts several `barplots` into one plot. It should plot the mean of `mean_swd` against the 6 `pot` variables separately, so that I can compare the mean scores on `mean_swd` for the individual groups of persons for which `..._pot == 1` (additionally, but not necessarily, grouping by the levels of these variables (1/0), so that I can compare `mean_swd` between those that have a potential of voting for that party vs those that don't).

As I don't have a single categorical variable by which to group I can't figure out how to code this and haven't found any solutions to the problem. The grouping solutions I found all work with single categorical variables for grouping. But I can't transform these six variables into one, as these `potentials` are not exclusive. The seperate `barplots` thus need to be calculated with varying individual observations. I also thought about grouping by boolean expressions but couldn't find any sources for this.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance. Also feel free to criticize the presentation of my problem, as this is my first posting ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Are you looking for something like this? Is this going in the right direction?

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(mean_swd = c(4.0000, 5.3333, 6.3333, 5.6666, 3.6666),
                 afd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 union_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 spd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 fdp_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 green_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 linke_pot = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))

dat <- df %>%
  melt(id.vars = "mean_swd") %>% 
  group_by(variable, value) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(mean_swd))

dat$value %<>% as.factor()

ggplot(dat, aes(variable, mean, fill = value)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @remek , `melt()` did the trick. Your solution wasn't exactly what I was looking for (tough it comes close) but it made clear that and how I need to structure my data BEFORE plotting. I omitted the `0` values and didn't use a stacked solution in the end. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? Feel free to clarify. I'm not sure if you'd rather have one that counts `1s` and `0s` and plots that against the average though.

```
df <- data.frame(mean_swd = c(4.0000, 5.3333, 6.3333, 5.6666, 3.6666),
                 afd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 union_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 spd_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 fdp_pot = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 green_pot = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 linke_pot = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 Group = c(1,2,3,4,5))
df1 <- gather(df, key = variables, value = value, mean_swd:linke_pot)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = variables, y = value, fill = factor(Group))) +
  facet_wrap(~Group) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(fill = "Groups")
```

[image]